# DB2 Identify unused index

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Is it possible to identify unused indexes? In our database we have a lot of indexes in the meanwhile. So it will be helpful when it will exist a system table to figure out these indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the LASTUSED column for view `SYSCAT.INDEXES` for **currently supported**
versions of Db2-LUW  and take care to fully understand the caveats mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscatindexes).

> Date when the index was last used by any DML statement to perform a
> scan, or used to enforce referential integrity constraints. This
> column is not updated when the index is used on an HADR standby
> database, nor is it updated when rows are inserted into the table on
> which the index is defined. The default value is '0001-01-01'. This
> value is updated asynchronously not more than once within a 24 hour
> period and might not reflect usage within the last 15 minutes.